# Primefaces: How can a component fit exactly inside a datatable

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to put some commandButtons and some progressBars inside a datatable.They look awful. How do i fit them **exactly** inside a dataTable cell? That is remove the extra space around the component which may be thought as 'padded' area.

NB:I tried using a panelgrid but the progress bars for some 'weird' reason did not appear as progressbars.Thanks

Comment: I suggest to take a step back from JSF and learn basic HTML/CSS first. The solution to this question is in CSS not in JSF.

Comment: oh!....thanks for the reply bro.I always appreciate your feedback. Infact i was just going thru your blog..I vote to delete the question...or do i leave it..someone may learn from it.?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles